# Divide csv file by Column length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, split

I have a .csv file with 52 columns and the length varies between 800.000 and 100.0000.000 rows. I need to convert this big file in multiple .csv files that all of them having 52 columns (same always) and 150.000 rows, (the last one doesn't matter the amount of rows, it is what it is left of it always with 150.000 rows or less). Examples of a **input.csv** of 550.00 rows:

Output:

```
split_1_of_4.csv(150.000 rows)
split_2_of_4.csv(150.000 rows)
split_3_of_4.csv(150.000 rows)
split_4_of_4.csv(100.000 rows)
```

Comment: Use read_line() or read_lines() and write to files

Answer (score 0):

I found a tutorial that splits CSV files using Python:
https://dzone.com/articles/splitting-csv-files-in-python

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thank you this was the best option

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to program this yourself, I suggest using GoCSV's [split](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#split) command:

> Split a CSV into multiple files.
>
> Usage:
>
> `gocsv split --max-rows N [--filename-base FILENAME] FILE`

You can find pre-built binaries here, [GoCSV Releases](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv/releases).

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to program this yourself, you need a way to know when you've hit your limit for the output file, which is just modulo math, `if I'TH_ROW % ROW_LIMIT == 0` then it's time to switch output files.

Here's the basics of that:

```py
ROW_LIMIT = 150_000

# get new CSV writer

for i in range(1, 600_002):

    # csv_writer.writerow(i'th row)

    if i % ROW_LIMIT == 0:

        print(f'Split rows {i-ROW_LIMIT+1:,} to {i:,}')

        # get "next/new" CSV writer

print(f'Split remaining rows up to {i:,}')
```

`range(1, 600_002)` is stand-in for an input CSV with 600_001 rows.  From this, I expect four CSVs with the max 150_000 rows, and one last CSV with just 1 row:

```
Split rows 1 to 150,000
Split rows 150,001 to 300,000
Split rows 300,001 to 450,000
Split rows 450,001 to 600,000
Split remaining rows up to 600,001
```

All that remains now is figuring out how to actually create a CSV writer and swap it out for a new one when it's "full".

I created a counting variable, `Outfile_Ct`, to keep track of which numbered-writer I'm on.  I start it at `0`, and every time I call my `get_next_writer()` func, it increments the count and returns the "next" numbered-writer:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv

ROW_LIMIT = 150_000

Outfile = None
Outfile_Ct = 0

def get_next_writer():
    global Outfile, Outfile_Ct

    if Outfile:
        Outfile.close()

    Outfile_Ct += 1

    num = f'{Outfile_Ct:02}'  # zero-pad for double-digit numbers
    fname = f'split_{num}.csv'
    Outfile = open(fname, 'w', newline='')

    return csv.writer(Outfile)

reader = csv.reader(open('gen_600001x1.csv', newline=''))

writer = get_next_writer()  # First time, will set Outfile_Ct to 1

header = next(reader)       # My input has a header
writer.writerow(header)     # I want to copy the header for every split-out file, see again below

for i, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
    writer.writerow(row)

    if i % ROW_LIMIT == 0:
        print(f'{Outfile.name}: rows {i-ROW_LIMIT+1} to {i}')
        writer = get_next_writer()
        writer.writerow(header)  # Copy header here, too

print(f'{Outfile.name}: remaining rows up to {i}')
```

I also keep track of `Outfile` so I can close it (which probably isn't important for this application) and print its name in a nice progress message.

My test file, `gen_600001x1.csv`, has a header and 600_001 rows (same as that range stand-in from earlier ).

When I run the split program on that CSV, I get:

```
split_01.csv: rows 1 to 150000
split_02.csv: rows 150001 to 300000
split_03.csv: rows 300001 to 450000
split_04.csv: rows 450001 to 600000
split_05.csv: remaining rows up to 600001
```

(which should also look really familiar)